# echoing href external link dropping http://, can't add it back in

Tags: php, html, security, hyperlink, echo

I am trying to echo a link and description that when clicked, will open that link. The link is in my database, and already includes http:// Here's what I've found.

```
href="'.trim($row['link']).'"
```

Gives me

```
http://localhost/venue/www.interplay.xyz
```

Notice that http:// has been already removed from the $row. Removing the trim() gives me the same result. I commented this out of my php page that inserts into the database.

```
$link = htmlentities($link)
```

but that made me vulnerable to inject code.

Also, I tried this, without commenting out the htmlentities.

```
href="http://'.trim($row['link']).'"
```

It gives me

```
about:blank
```

Don't know if that helps. We'll, here's my entire php for selecting and echoing the link. Please find the issue, or give me an alternative to htmlentities for securing this form. Thank you.

```
<?php
//selected latest uploaded shout link
$sqlShout    = "SELECT *
              FROM shout
              WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM shout ) ;";

//display latest uploaded shout link
if ($resultShout = mysqli_query($con, $sqlShout))
{
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultShout)) 
          {
$_SESSION['shoutid'] = $row['id'];
    echo '<a target="_blank" href="http://'.trim($row['link']).'"><center>
    <font size="6">'.trim($row['title']).'</font><br>
    <font size="2">'.trim($row['link']).'</font>
    </a></center> ';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: check the value of `$row['link']`

Comment: See below for correction

Comment: whoops, the site auto condenses links. http:// + www.google.com

Comment: so you got the problem

Comment: No, stackoverflow will condense the link. I can't type it in this box. What I see when I echo it to the page is the link including http://.

Comment: The problem is somewhere in your database. The code you show doesn't alter the `$row['link']` value, it only [trims](http://www.php.net/trim) the value. Which means : (quote php.net) '*Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string*'. So look into how the values are inserted, and you'll find a solution.

Comment: Could I use the working unprotected solution I came up with, and find another way to protect myself from code inject beside htmlentities in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. @LinkinTED is correct. Problem maybe with your value of `$row['link']`.

Please check value of `$row['link']`. I replace $row['link'] with variable $row1.

i got expected answers.

```
<?php
  $row1='http://www.google.com';
  $answer=trim($row1);
  echo $answer ."</br>"; // ...........1

  echo "http://".trim($row1)."";//..........2 
 ?>
```

Answers are as follows:

```
http://www.google.com

http://http://www.google.com
```

`trim()` function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will strip these characters:

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
 "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
 "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
 "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
 "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
 "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

Comment: $row is the variable, and it's an array, which is why I use $row['link']. $row['link'] itself is not a variable. How do I replace it with $row1? In the while statement?

Comment: You defined $row1 as what you wanted. I'm retrieving a different link each time, so I can't define $row1, I can retrieve a a row from the database, which I use $row to get the link, and then use $row['link'], where link is the variable key to the actual link, whatever it might be. while($row = http:// wwww.google.com) obviously isn't an option. I think I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Ah, I got it. I put $answer = trim($row['link']); and it worked even with htmlentities inserted links. Not sure if that's what you were suggesting, but i gave you the check because the key was to store my trimmed row in another variable. Thank you for your help. Sorry if I seemed skeptical.